# VS Code intellisense for Javascript built-in function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In Javascript for some methods, I don't see the suggestions. For example `indexOf`, `charCodeAt` and so on. Is it possible to activate suggestions for these built-in Javascript keywords?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should leverage VS Code ability to work with JSDoc.

As you can see without JSDoc, VS Code can't infer that `bar` is a string. After documenting the parameter properly, it is able to make some meaningful suggestions:

[image]

Comment: For those that are wondering, this works for variables that are utilized inside of a function, like in the example, but does not work for variable declarations like `const foo = bar.[intellisense-here]`

Comment: @JDunken it _can_ if you add the relevant bit of JSDoc to your variable declaration. e.g. `/** @type {string} */ var foo;`